# Defining C++ Preprocessor macros with SCons

Tags: c++, macros, scons

I'm trying to define a preprocessor macro within Scons for building a larger C/C++ project.

One of the libraries I'm using needs ALIGN defined. To be more specific, if I add

```
#define ALIGN(x) __attribute((aligned(x)))
```

to the header file of said library, it compiles fine. However, I should be able to specify this at build time, as this is how the library intends on being used. I know in CMake, I would be able to define the macro using something like

```
SET(ALIGN_DECL "__attribute__((aligned(x)))")
```

Defining *constants* in Scons like this

```
myEnv.Append(CPPDEFINES = ['IAMADEFINEDCONSTANT'])
```

works fine, but definine a *macro* in this way doesn't work. 
What gives?

Edit: fixed typo

Comment: how did you try creating the macro?

Comment: I was omitting the equals sign. Adding it got me another error (in a shell script) but that was easily solved by adding whitespace to either side of the character. 

Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to do it on Linux with g++ as follows:

**SConscript**

```
env = Environment()
env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['MAX(x,y)=(x>y ? x:y)'])
env.Program(target = 'main', source = 'main.cc')
```

**main.cc**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int a = 3;
  int b = 5;

  // MAX() will be defined at compile time
  cout << "Max is " << MAX(a, b) << endl;
}
```

**Compilation**

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o main.o -c "-DMAX(x,y)=(x>y ? x:y)" main.cc
g++ -o main main.o
scons: done building targets.
```

**Execution**

```
./main
Max is 5
```